# question mark value not mentioned in sql statement, still query working how?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

my sql query is

```
"SELECT * FROM EMPL_POOL_TOOL_DATA WHERE abc= ? AND xyz= ? AND WRITE_ACCESS = ? AND (COORDINATOR= ? OR  SUB_COORDINATOR = ? OR MANAGER = ?)";
```

And i am giving question marks values like this

```
psmt.setString(1, someValue);
psmt.setString(2, someValue);
psmt.setString(3, someValue);
```

I am not mentioning 4,5 and 6th question mark values.
Why it is not throwing any exception and working fine???

Comment: use single quotes like `'?'`

Comment: @J.Zend No. That's not how prepared statements work.

Comment: ok...i tought that the value filled with '?'..

Comment: What is the calling code written in? Language? Database connection library?

Comment: you are obviously using a framework that take care of missing parameters and removes their parts from the final SQL statement being sent to the database.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i am using ojdbc and java